# :hover and disappearing scrollbar in Edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

When I drag a scroll bar up or down in Edge - see below for version details, the scrollbar disappears along with properties I defined in `:hover` pseudoclass. In my example, the background goes back to blue. Is there anything I can do to fix this? All seems to work fine in other browsers.

JSBin with example: 
http://jsbin.com/johiwulige/edit?html,css,output

```
div.ex3 {
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 90px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

div.ex3:hover {
    background-color: red;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Browser details:

Microsoft Edge 41.16299.611.0

Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299

@ 2017 Microsoft

Comment: Works fine also on version 42.x :/

Answer (score -1):

I am available with version below.

Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0

Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134

Below is my testing result. I can see that it is working fine.

[image]

So if you are still having issue with Microsoft Edge 41.16299.611.0 then try to upgrade your MS Edge with latest version may help you to solve your issue.